# Confusion about how the transition between Cartesian and polar coordinates is done

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

So right now, I'm really confused with polar coordinates. Being really familiar with the ordinary Cartesian coordinate, I do not get how the **transition between Cartesian to polar coordinate** is done.

So I've been reading various resources, and in one source, they mentioned about **shifting the origin to the centre** of a square and then calculate the polar coordinates, and in other source, they didn't mention anything about shifting the origin to the centre and calculate the polar coordinates right off the bat. So I'm confused **which is which**?

Do I shift the origin to the centre and calculate the polar coordinates then or perform the calculation without doing so?

Comment: Those are directions for doing two different things.  What do *you* want to do?  Do you want to convert from a Cartesian coordinate system with a given origin to a polar coordinate system with a **different** origin or do you want to convert from a Cartesian coordinate system with a given origin to a polar coordinate system with the **same* origin?

Comment: @user247327 different origin which is the centre

Comment: "Centre" of what?

Comment: @user247327 centre of a square block of 8x8 dimension.